# Making a password type program that needs to accept letter and number combinations?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am making a shopping list program. For this program, I need to be able to type in a user input that accepts both number (1564, 121,1, etc) and word (hello, goodbye, etc) combinations. The program reads numbers just fine, but it cannot process words. Thank you in advance. The part of the code I am stuck with is below:

```
int code, option, count = 0;
double  quantity, price, cost;
string description;

cin >> code;



while ((code != 123456789) && (count < 2))
{


    cout << "Incorrect code, try again \n";
    cin >> code;
    count++;

    if (count == 2)
    {

        cout << "max # of tries reached. Goodbye. \n";
        system("pause");

    }

}
```

Comment: You have to use the lowest common denominator, which is always read string data and convert to a number if you need to.

Comment: and if the password can contain spaces, go directly to getline().

Answer (score 1):

Your `code` variable is now an int. If you wanted that to be a string, declare it so: `std::string code;`. Note that you might need to `#include <string>` in the very beginning. Also, if you want to compare it with numbers, either you call something like `atoi()` (string has `.cstr()`), or better yet, you might just compare it with "123456789". HTH.

Comment: Thanks to all for your input. After digging around I ended up using the cin.ignore and cin.clear commands to make it read a word string and then dump it out after.